# Do something on button click inside of footer in a tableView

Tags: xcode, swift

I have a tableView that has a header, a footer and a prototype cell for dynamic purposes. I have a `Sign Out` button in the footer but can't figure out how to get it linked up with a function. I setup a segue to go back to a login page but I want an alert box to ask for confirmation first so I need to somehow call a function.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Footer") as! MenuTableViewCell
    footerCell.logout.targetForAction("logOutButtonClicked", withSender: self)
    return footerCell
}
```

This is what I have now, but upon click it crashes and gives me

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[.MenuTableViewCell logOutButtonClick:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffce28615d0'
```

I have a function called logOutButtonClicked that looks like this...

```
    func logOutButtonClicked(){
    let alertView = UIAlertController(title: "Log Out?", message: "Are you sure you want to Log Out?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    alertView.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Log Out", style: .Default, handler: {(alertAction) -> Void in
        self.logOut()}))
    presentViewController(alertView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func logOut(){
    performSegueWithIdentifier("goHome", sender: self)
}
```

Edit:
I've also tried `footerCell.logout.addTarget(self, action: "logOutButtonClicked", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`
 but that gives the same error as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by erasing all of the events and outlets corresponding to the button (the ones you find when you right click on it) and then rewriting the function like so...

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let footerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Footer") as! MenuTableViewCell
    footerCell.logout.addTarget(self, action: "logOutButtonClicked", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    return footerCell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a function called "logOutButtonClicked" since you specified by adding the targetForAction, it would look something like this:

```
func logOutButtonClicked() {
```

}

Comment: I have that, sorry I should have mentioned that. I've made an edit that includes it